# Tracking down the origin of a VS2k8 error message?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have several maps containing a multitude of classes in my VC++ project, some of them default constructable, others not. When trying to build, I get a "no appropriate default constructor available" error. The problem is that the error is listed to occur in line 173 of map.cpp, which is the code for `operator[]`. It would seem that I'm accidentally calling `operator[]` (which implicitly calls the mapped type's default constructor) on one of my non-default constructable maps, but VS doesn't give me any info on where the error originated.

How can I find the part in my code that's causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking inside the error list window.  Which I don't use that often for C++ projects.

Go to the output window and check a little further down, you should be able to double click the line that will bring you to the type in question.

Doing a search for `: error` inside the output window is very common for me as well as `: fatal` to find the source of the errors.  Also if you have C++ keyboard shortcuts setup you can keep hitting `F4` to go down the list of errors.

To reset to the default C++ keyboard mappings:
`Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`
Then reset keyboard mappings to: `Visual C++ 6`.

Comment: Ah yes, found a line number in the Output window. Thanks.